# Making google analytics ID a variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces, google-analytics

My app serves multiple domains which I understand should be done by namespaces which I'm researching. Since multiple domains should have multiple analytics ID:s I get the analytics ID from the code but I want to make it even more configurable:

```
    if os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST').endswith('.br') \
        or os.environ['SERVER_NAME'].endswith('.br'):
        data[u'analytics'] = 'UA-637933-12'
else:
        data[u'analytics'] = 'UA-637933-18'

    self.response.out.write(template.render(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                            'templates', name + '.html'), data))
```

The above sets analytics ID to ..-12 if it's my brazilian domain and to the other ID ...-18 if it is my dot com. But this is only for 2 domains and it's not easiliy generalizable. How can I achieve this function in a more scientific and scalable way so that it becomes easy to add my application to a domain without manually adding the domain to my application?

I suppose namespaces is the way to go here since the domains are google apps domains but I don't understand [how to use namespaces](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/guestbook_namespaces/appengine_config.py):

```
def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
  """Determine which namespace is to be used for a request.

  The value of _NAMESPACE_PICKER has the following effects:

  If _USE_SERVER_NAME, we read server name
  foo.guestbook-isv.appspot.com and set the namespace.

  If _USE_GOOGLE_APPS_DOMAIN, we allow the namespace manager to infer
  the namespace from the request.

  If _USE_COOKIE, then the ISV might have a gateway page that sets a
  cookie called 'namespace', and we set the namespace to the cookie's value
  """
  name = None

  if _NAMESPACE_PICKER == _USE_SERVER_NAME:
    name = os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
  elif _NAMESPACE_PICKER == _USE_GOOGLE_APPS_DOMAIN:
    name = namespace_manager.google_apps_namespace()
  elif _NAMESPACE_PICKER == _USE_COOKIE:
    cookies = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE', None)
    if cookies:
      name = Cookie.BaseCookie(cookies).get('namespace')

  return name
```

I suppose I should use the namespace manager, get the namespace and set the analytics ID according to the namespace but how?

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your question: You shouldn't use os.environ if you can avoid it; instead, fetch the relevant data from the handler's `self.request` (`self.request.host` in this case).

Comment: @Nick Johnson It's very relevant since I want lose the low-level os calls - I don't think a request handler should access the `os` function directly(?) Any improvement is relevant if you ask me. I'm going to prioritize the improvements, got some minus score for asking questions where the answer was part of the question... -2 for asking and +9 for their answer that says my question contained the answer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with a Python dict:

```
analytics_ids = {
  'mydomain.br': 'UA-637933-12',
  'mydomain.com': 'UA-637933-18',
}

data['analytics'] = analytics_ids[self.request.host]
```

If you have other per-domain stats, you may want to make each dictionary entry a tuple, a nested dict, or a configuration object of some sort, then fetch and store it against the current request for easy reference.

If you want to be able to reconfigure this at runtime, you could use a datastore model, but that will impose extra latency on requests that need to fetch it; it seems likely to me that redeploying each time you add a domain isn't likely to be a problem in your case.

Namespaces are tangential to what you're doing. They're a good way to divide up the rest of your data between different domains, but they're not useful for dividing up configuration data.

Comment: That looks very good, generalizable to more than 2 domains and something I can work on better instead of my very primitive "solution"

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have two instances of the same application running. 
Instead of fiddling with namespaces, I suggest you turn the Analytics ID into a configuration variable.

That is, either store it in a config file or a database your web is using. Then set one ID for each deployment (in each place your web is running from) and fetch it in the runtime.

For example:

Config file:

```
analyticsId="UA-637933-12"
```

Code:

```
data[u'analytics'] = getValueFromConfig("analyticsId")
```

where getValueFromConfig is a function you define to read the appropriate value. (To use configuration files effortlessly, you may use the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module.)

Now you've gained a lot more flexibility - you don't have to do any checking and switching at runtime. You only have to define the value once per web site and be done with it.

Comment: I don't think he's using multiple instances of the app - otherwise none of this would be necessary.

Comment: I think it works with only one instance. I hope you understand that I want to be able to add a domain without reprogramming my app so it can't be in the python, it could be a config file or data layer that gets cached. A typical use case would be: "deploy a russian version to a russian domain" and then I shouldn't be forced to reprogram my python, I should be able to "add" via an admin ui which can be done if I use either a dynamic properties object like a plain file that my app can change and cache or simply a table in the datastore for the relations between apps and domains. Thanks!

Comment: A tried a config.py file but I couldn't make it work well. I will use a dict that Mr Johnson suggested which looks very neat and O(1)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you tried storing the config in a .py file? Don't forget that you're not supposed to handle config files as python source files. If you are unsure how to do it properly, see the Python page examples (found on link above).